# uialertview called more than once

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uialertview

It's Irritating ...!!!

I googled about this problem, found some **`Relative Questions`** but not **`Satisfactory Answers`**.

So I have One `- (IBAction)` method that adds some `UITextField's` Values to `NSMutableArray` when **`"Add"`** Button is Clicked. I am simply trying to show `UIAlertView`, if the UITextField is **empty**.

**My Code :**

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
       if ([textField1.text length]==0 || [textField2.text length]==0 || !someFlag)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Please Enter Valid Data..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
        else
        {
             // Code to add textField's value to Array.
        }
}
```

**My Problem :**

Whenever I press **"Add"** Button with **empty textField** , `UIAlertView` appears **thrice**.

**1)** For the First Time It appears with `"Close"` Button. (I have never added...) It disappears within some time.

**2)** Second Time It appears with **"OK"** Button. (That's what I added...) It disappears when I press **"OK"** Button.

**3)** Third Time It appears with **"Close"** Button again. It disappears when I press **"Close"** Button.

**EDIT :**

Similar Question : [UIAlertView Pops Up Three Times per Call Instead of Just Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273283/uialertview-pops-up-three-times-per-call-instead-of-just-once). 
Can someone help me to found solution from this ?

Comment: Problem is with some other code not this code. Check other code.

Comment: Can you show the alertView that appears with "Close" button

Comment: have you try it with the condition [textField.text isEqualToString:@""]

Comment: You should not be comparing to NULL. Can you confirm that the method is being called three times?

Comment: Problem might be with the delegate method.

Comment: How do you add the action to your interface? Only with Interface Builder? Do you add an action with `addTarget` method of the `UIButton`?

Comment: @who9vy : only with IB.

Comment: @BaZinga : I tried that but no Luck at All.

Comment: Just Check UPDATE in my Question...

Comment: Then what about that **@"close"** stuff ur code don't have @"close" anywhere.

Comment: @rptwsthi : That's what I want to know. When I run the code with if ([textField1.text isEqualToString:@""]) , it works perfectly...

Comment: tell me when u get that.. :)

Comment: @Vin you can post your answer as answer, that will be more feasible for finders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strange....!!!**

Sometimes it happens that you **Totally Neglect** certain lines of your code When you are **Over-Irritated**. It happend to me also. I neglected one method that is called from `-addButtonPressed` Method , Which has One `AlertView` (With `"Close"` Button of course) inside it.

That's the Solution itself !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains no issues. There's not 3 it's only 2 alerts. here's the flow of alert view:

1. As soon as you click on `add` button there called 2 selector (may be one inside other OR two IBAction by one button) which contains alert view code in them
2. Now that alert2 (with cancel button) get called before alert1(with ok button)
3. Then alert1 get called and hide alert2
4. Now when you resolve alert1(by clicking on ok button) alert2 shows up again

Now what you need to do is to check "if your button is not connected with 2 IBActions", which that should be as you have no such code to call another alert in this method. And check if it helps.

Comment: No, my "Add" Button is only connected with addButtonPressed ...

Comment: Can u upload that on git and provide a link. so I can check for the Issue

Comment: Just Check UPDATE in my Question...

Comment: +1 for showing the Direction and your Effort. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

yes I have face same problem but my case is different than you .

1. You should try `[textfield.text isEqualToString:@""];` because this is the standard way to compare empty text field in Objective-C.
2. Check that you dismiss your alert view properly sometimes we don't give focus on dismissing the alert view so because of that your alert view remain active and when you reopen you are app it shows 2 to 3 times depending on your condition. So you can use the delegate **did dismiss alert view with button index** for dismissing the alert view in **view did disappear**. I am not sure but it should work for you Good luck dude.
3. And I am not sure but I think your IBAction Button is overwrite for each time when you clicked in any button so you should check it also.

Comment: Just Check UPDATE in my Question...

Comment: +1 for your First Point.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code......let me know it is working or not!!!!

what you have done is you have given other button nil 2 times..so may be  that is the problem...

Happy Coding!!!!

```
 if ([textField.text length]==0)
    {

      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Please Enter Valid Data..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    }
```

Comment: yeah I tried that but not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
   if ([textField.text length]==0)
    {
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Information",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Txt is  Empty!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show]; alert = nil;
    }
    else
    {
         // Code to add textField's value to Array.
    }
}
```

First check that how many times you call `IBAction` method when Button tapped???

Other wise put instance of `UIAlertView` is a **public**.. I mean put in `.h file` and access it as `self.yourAlertViewName` in `.m file`.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try compare like this.

```
if([testBox.text isEqualToString:@""]
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:errorDesc
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Check Comments in my Question , I already tried this way...

Answer (score -1):

Check with below code:

```
if ([textField.text length]==0)
{
UIAlertView *objAlertMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp"
                                                       message:@"Please Enter Valid Data..."
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
[objAlertMsg show];
[objAlertMsg release];
}
```

Check that, I have set delegate to "nil" instead of "self". And make sure you have not implement delegate in view controller if it's not required.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers.

Comment: I tried this but no Luck ... !!

Comment: plz check updated code, and let me know if it's success.

Comment: yeah I tried that but not working...