# How to make the UIAlertView call itself again?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview, uialertview

Below is the scenario.

1. I have created a UIAlertView in viewDidLoad of the Controller in which I display the Alert.

   ```
   loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                               message:@"Ok"
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
   [loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
   ```
2. I call it as [alert show] and it is displayed.
3. When user press Ok, it goes to textEndEditing delegate method and from if nil/worng value was entered, I call [alert show] again.

   ```
   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
   if ([textField.text length] > 0)
   {

   }
   else
   {
    NSLog(@"Checking");
    [loginAlert show];
   }
   }
   ```

But its not displayed again. Please tell me what to do?

Comment: give some code. cant understand exactly what you are upto

Comment: do you have your UIAlertView object class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your alert view delegate to self.

```
loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                        message:@"Ok"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];

[loginAlert show];
```

Then in the alert view delegate method check the length of the text and show the the alert again if empty.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([[loginAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Checking");
            [loginAlert show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works perfectly for my requirements. I guess I overdid things a bit and ended up in textfield delegate method and all.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `delegate:nil`, put `delegate:self`

```
loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                            message:@"Ok"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                        message:@"Ok"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; 


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField==yourTextField) {
        if ([yourTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || yourTextField.text == nil) {
            [yourAlert show];
        }
    }
}
```

**Also see this for your problem:**

1. [Keep UIAlertView displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200616/keep-uialertview-displayed)
2. [uialertview called more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751187/uialertview-called-more-than-once)

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate `self` instead of `nil` and implement my code.

```
    loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                                message:@"Ok"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; 



 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
     {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @hitesh what do you mean ?

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

Answer (score 0):

How about making it simple .. ?

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([textField.text length] > 0)
{

}
else
{
 NSLog(@"Checking");
 loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check"
                                            message:@"Ok"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[loginAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; 
 [loginAlert show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
       // Your code write in this method and show your alert 
    }
   else
   {
        [loginalert show];
   }
}
```

i hope this code useful for you.